# My First R Shiny App

Tags: shiny

I've spent two days trying to create a Shiny app to no avail. It's fine just running the examples but when I want to modify it for my own preference, I just get constant errors and lack of functionality.

I have a simple dataset of 100 X observations and 100 Y observations. I want to plot histograms of both X and Y with slider inputs for bins. I also want to create a scatterplot of Y on X. I'd really appreciate some help here.

I'm not new to R but I'm new to Shiny. Is there a way I can use ggplot to create the visuals?

Many thanks.

Comment: Start with the built-in R functionality as well as the shiny example template. Use `shiny::renderPlot()`. Inside `renderPlot()`, return `hist()` (for the histogram) and `plot()` (for the scatter plot) with the respective parameters you mentioned in your post. It seems that X and Y are static, so you can store them in your global scope, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick example with two different layouts. Use one of the ui.R of course. Put global.R in the same folder with ui.R and server.R

ui.R v1

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

      titlePanel("Quick Shiny Example"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
           sliderInput("xBins",
                       "Number of bins for X variable:",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 50,
                       value = 30),
           sliderInput("yBins",
                       "Number of bins for Y variable:",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 50,
                       value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("xDistPlot"),
           plotOutput("yDistPlot"),
           plotOutput("xyScatterPlot")
        )
      )
    ))
```

ui.R v2

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Quick Shiny Example"),
            fluidRow(
                    column(width = 4, 
                           sliderInput("xBins",
                                       "Number of bins for X variable:",
                                       min = 1,
                                       max = 50,
                                       value = 30)
                    ),
                    column(width = 4,
                           sliderInput("yBins",
                                       "Number of bins for Y variable:",
                                       min = 1,
                                       max = 50,
                                       value = 30)
                    ),
                    column(width = 4)
            ),
            fluidRow(
                    column(width = 4, 
                           plotOutput("xDistPlot")
                    ),
                    column(width = 4,
                           plotOutput("yDistPlot")
                    ),
                    column(width = 4, 
                           plotOutput("xyScatterPlot")
                    )
            )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      output$xDistPlot <- renderPlot({
        g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) 
        g <- g + geom_histogram(bins = input$xBins)
        g
      })
      output$yDistPlot <- renderPlot({
              g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = y)) 
              g <- g + geom_histogram(bins = input$yBins)
              g
      })
      output$xyScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
              g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) 
              g <- g + geom_point()
              g
      })

    })
```

global.R

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = rnorm(100),
    y = rnorm(100)*2
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, with random numbers for `X` and `Y`, just as a quick idea. Adding ggplot to this should be easy.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("nrBinsX", "Number of bins to display for X", min = 2, max = 10, value = 5),
    plotOutput("histX"),
    sliderInput("nrBinsY", "Number of bins to display for Y", min = 2, max = 10, value = 5),
    plotOutput("histY"),
    plotOutput("scatterXY")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  dataFrame <- data.frame (
    "X" = sample(100,100,replace = T),
    "Y" = sample(100,100,replace = T)
  )

  getHist <- function (var,nr){
    return (hist(
      x = var,
      breaks = seq(0,100,100/nr),
      freq = T
    ) )
  }

    output$histX <- renderPlot({
      return(
        getHist( var = dataFrame$X,
                 nr = input$nrBinsX
        ) ) })

    output$histY <- renderPlot({
      return(       return(
        getHist( var = dataFrame$Y,
                 nr = input$nrBinsY
        )
      ) ) })

  output$scatterXY <- renderPlot({
    return(
      plot(x = dataFrame$X,
           y = dataFrame$Y)
    )
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I have spent a lot of hours searching on line for a clear, well-structured example like this. :)